# Trying To Scan IP For Getting Domain Name In Python With Socket

Tags: python, sockets, dns, ip

I am trying to scan domain name from ip address. 
That's why i took a input from file and split that, amd changing the last 3digit with loop .  and checking all random ip. But It Shows Nothing. And there is a valid ip with domain.

```
f = open('ip.txt', 'r')
r = f.readline()
f.close()
ips = r.split(".")
ipc = ips[0] + "." + ips[1] + "." + ips[2] + "."
for i in range(0, 256):
    ipm = ipc + str(i)
    ip = str('"' + ipm + '"')
    try:
        socket.gethostbyaddr(ip)
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: it shows nothing because you do not print anything, nor do you even capture the result of `socket.gethostbyaddr` into some variable... Nor do you really treat exceptions in any sensible way...

Comment: Also, what is your real goal there? You will learn little information with this as not all IP addresses have PTR records (and you are of course forgetting about IPv6) and even if they have how do you think this relates to a "domain name"? Maybe you were asking about an hostname? Because otherwise "*I am trying to scan domain name from ip address.*" makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

Your indentation here is wrong, try this:

```
for i in range(0,256):
    ipm=ipc+str(i)
    ip=str('"'+ipm+'"')
    try: 
        socket.gethostbyaddr(ip)
    except:
        pass
```

Edit: I also suspect that you can simply do `ip = str(ipm)`, without needing to add the extra double quotes.

Comment: @AndroWizard could it be the double quotes thing I mentioned?